# Should the DNS and DHCP server be on the same machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, group-policy, dhcp

We are experiencing an issue with users not being mapped to their corresponding network drives during login. I verified that the logon script is correct, and it works if I run it manually so I suspect there is some kind of network issue.

When I run gpupdate, I get an error that states that:

> Group Policy failed because of lack network connectivity to the domain controller

I can ping our DC server immediately after I get this error. I figured this was somehow related to the DNS and/or DHCP server. The DNS service is running on the DC and the DHCP service is running on a Pfsense system.

Should I move the DHCP server to the DC?

Comment: What does the evidence tell you? You can ping the DC immediately after the error, which would indicate that the machine has a valid ip configuration, which would tend to rule out DHCP as the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I move the DHCP server to the DC?

There's no reason to. In fact, it's best security practice *not* to run it on a DC. The only reason I ever set up a DHCP server on a DC is in SMB networks that don't have any other choice.

Comment: My DHCP server is pointing to DC as its DNS server but how is DNS supposed to get its info from the DHCP if it is in two different locations?

Comment: That comment doesn't make much sense. Do you mean that your DHCP server has Option 6 (DNS Servers) configured to tell clients to use your DCs as DNS servers? If so, there's nothing Windows/DC specific about that option. You can set it on any RFC compliant DHCP server.

Comment: If you're referring to DHCP updating the client DNS records in your AD zone, then you shouldn't be doing that anyway, you're asking for zone poisoning. You should be doing authenticated updates only and letting the client machines update their own A records. Letting DHCP be a DNS Update Proxy is usually a bad idea in 99% of design scenerios.

Answer (score -2):

DHCP and DNS on the same server should not have have any issues. If it's possible try to put static ip on a host and try the whole process again. If no problem occurs you MIGHT have a problem with the DHCP server.

You can also also unplug the lan connection and replug it after a while to check how long it takes DHCP to provide an IP.

From my experience if it's no problem (for SMB) or management issue static ip is the way to go.

Hope it helps.

Comment: -1 for even suggesting that addresses be statically assigned. For servers yes but not for workstations. Doing so just creates more trouble than it could ever hope to solve.

Comment: Thats why i said if it's no problem. Depends on the situation. Thanks for you comment.